# Cómo detectar ruta (de red) no disponible

Tags: vba

Estoy desarrollando en Excel un código para guardar unoos datos a usar en otras planillas en archivos ".dat" en una ubicación de red
Cómo puede detectar que se desconectó la red o que la ruta no está disponible asi mediante un if guardar en una ruta local? algo así como

```
if ''funcion para detectar que la ruta es accesible'' then open "\\ruta de red\archivo.dat" else open "D:\archivo.dat"
```

Comment: Hola. Detectar una LAN del tipo UDC no es tan simple, es más práctico detectar un archivo existente ahí, por ende ¿Ese archivo DAT existe previamente siempre? o ¿Hay en la ruta de la red algún archivo que siempre esté presente en una  de sus carpetas?

Answer (score 1):

prueba algo como esto

```
Dim fso AS Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FolderExists("\\ruta de red") = True Then
    MsgBox "Existe."
Else
    MsgBox "NO Existe."
End If
```

Comment: Procura siempre, por simple que sea, dar una breve explicación de por qué el código resuelve la pregunta :)

Comment: Lamento informar que la solución propuesta no funciona. En todos los casos me muestra que no existe

Comment: Hablé muy rápido. SI FUNCIONA. Apuntando a una ruta de red, no solo el nombre de la pc destino

Comment: Hola @leo3467. Si te ha servido el código porfa marca la respuesta cómo útil